# adding data input into a empty data frame in R using shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am fairly new to shiny and R I am trying to make a user interface for the amount of money used in different companies. I made a empty data frame, and was trying to add the input from the user to the data frame, but the app crashes. Any assistance would be great please!

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(Company = character(), Goods = character(),GoodsType = character(), 
             Number = integer(), Cost = double(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
     titlePanel("Cost tool "),

      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(inputId = "Company", label = "Company",
                      choices = list("Company 1", "Company 2 " , " Company 3 "), selected = ""),

          radioButtons(inputId = "Goods", label = "Select bought goods",inline = TRUE,
               choices = list("Food", "Electronics","Books"), selected = ""),

          selectInput(inputId = "GoodsType", label = " Types of Goods",
              choices = list(" Milk", "Eggs" , "vegetables" ,"Games Consoles",
               "headphones", "phones", "mystery","fiction","horror"), selected = ""),

          textInput(inputId = "Number", label = " How many?: ",
                    value = ""),

           textInput(inputId = "Cost", label = "Cost",
                    value = ""),

          actionButton("submit","Submit")


  ),
    mainPanel(
     dataTableOutput("CostTable")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output){

 observeEvent(input$submit, {

 df[1,] <- data.frame(input$Company,input$Goods,input$GoodsType, input$Number, input$Cost)


   })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When constructing the dataframe, integers are `numeric()`. I've also added the `reactiveValues` so you can put your dataframe into. If you want the dataframe to reset on evey visit you can put `v$df <- data.frame(Company =...` into the `server` part of the app

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Cost tool "),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(inputId = "Company", label = "Company",
                        choices = list("Company 1", "Company 2 " , " Company 3 "), selected = ""),
            radioButtons(inputId = "Goods", label = "Select bought goods",inline = TRUE,
                         choices = list("Food", "Electronics","Books"), selected = ""),
            selectInput(inputId = "GoodsType", label = " Types of Goods",
                        choices = list(" Milk", "Eggs" , "vegetables" ,"Games Consoles",
                                       "headphones", "phones", "mystery","fiction","horror"), selected = ""),
            textInput(inputId = "Number", label = " How many?: ",value = ""),
            textInput(inputId = "Cost", label = "Cost",value = ""),
            actionButton("submit","Submit")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput("CostTable")
        )
    )
)


v <- reactiveValues()
v$df <- data.frame(Company = character(), Goods = character(),GoodsType = character(), 
                   Number = numeric(), Cost = numeric(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

server <- function(input, output, session){

    observeEvent(input$submit,{
        req(input$Company,input$Goods,input$GoodsType,input$Number,input$Cost)
        tmp <- data.frame(Company = input$Company,Goods = input$Goods,GoodsType = input$GoodsType, Number = input$Number,Cost = input$Cost)
        v$df <- rbind(v$df,tmp)
    })
    output$CostTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        v$df
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: your answer breaks the display of the table with one letter per column

Comment: still not working, the words are split across columns

Comment: I think its to do what version of DT are u rinning, all works for me

Comment: I forgot to load DT at the beginning of the app, you should add a ```library``` call in your answer, it works now

Comment: I've another machine where I was able to reproduce the issue, adding `DT::` solved it

Comment: Is there a way to keep the dataframe in the R environment when the shiny ui window is closed? `v` is in the environment as a reactivevalues object, so it is not obvious how to access the data.

Comment: And answering my comment: `isolate(reactiveValuesToList(v))`, courtesy of https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/reactiveValuesToList.html